# Debug DKIM in email

Tags: email, email-signature, dkim

A friend is sending me emails through a mailing list, and my IAP always flag those emails and prepend a `<DKIM>` tag in the subject. Some tools indeed indicate the DKIM signature of the email is invalid.

But How can I debug that to understand where the problem happened ? By looking at the source I can see the email went through several hops, and there are multiple DKIM signatures in there, how do I know which one went wrong ?

EDIT

The DKIM references I can find in the header are like

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=from:subject:to:message-id:date:user-agent:mime-version
         :content-transfer-encoding;
        bh=O9BCwGETD2cTR4ieKg/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=;
        b=XXXXXXXxxxxxXXX/xDOA2+lNlM3LtohFOuZZfeYLvCkHpf68kNFW
         1at6O96bhMhrKeKigEBmYXIRK+URXPaLFCLdOIELpbLR0JW0/XXXXXXX/XXX+H4ff
         Jtlp1o22FOwxDpoVWVh8NPlwHR9VVX8yYHHfVzq7t4sfSspY0w7SaBM4INOrBZW9b6MO
         irJRq4GV/k2k1RLLzyU3tfOXdmlNBg+0XNWpB6OSMFQmbT+n2rfq45OIG5JszKqk0LOo
         beZQlCRn6sTfkRXYk30gnCIRN6DW+GR8WZV848RHyPhC4V4AWYDQU4UfDIZGAULNqrHc
         Aq+Q==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
        h=x-gm-message-state:from:subject:to:message-id:date:user-agent
         :mime-version:content-transfer-encoding;
        bh=O9BCwGETD2cTR4ieKg/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=;
        b=GwOOEQjePvsonmu0U5bqFB2wzm6dIkx9t6igZwd9tE9aXGQqt722CriV18FQZy0aDq
         AC/pI166KHuu3jgRM8j6ix6PXA3MHGs8xuLAswwJ/XX/XXXXXXXX/XXXXX
         Bf+yoIFl3sOg4619Ky3pbI1aUFR2KLjNry0rRylzmr5cA7MNjJG5x0caNzFRRrAkGli/
         jBWFmyuM1mJh+4MLIPBxiG5p6k4JffCz5hKIx/qor94CD65c0RBw/rlzsxAFu6cHqhPk
         v28+gObg633kInFnoYsNpcxPWleiH0uVKkapspDyr5LvXvYaupnvORQp5A6v63zPZT2v
         zkjw==
```

I'm afraid that doesn't help me much to understand what in the hell happened...

Comment: The header should indicate which one of the DKIM signatures is invalid.

Comment: @Ramhound sure I can find some DKIM stuff in the header... but then what ? (see my edit, I'm not sure what informations are in there so I anonymised a bit)